# Continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Online: Loss of conectivity

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I've followed each step of this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

When I make check-in It triggers the build, but I receive the error message:
This build has been stopped automatically by the server due to loss of connectivity to the build machine.

I can't find a solution for this problem. I'm retrying the build but without succes.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Bizarro issue that showed up on my system without notice.

After a lot of troubleshooting, I found that I had not mapped the Visual Studio solution to my local drive.  After mapping, resetting security permissions, it began to work.  Sorry, I dont have a clear solution for you.